# Tooltip with series with several frequencies

Tags: tooltip, highcharts

In the demo site, there is an example with series comparison (http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare).

In this example every series has values at same date times.
What I have to plot is several series but each series has there own frequency (ie : one daily, one hourly and one every 10 minutes).
It works but the tooltip displays :

- the 3 values when we are over a full day date time
- the hourly and the 10' values when we are over full hour date time
- only the 10' value when we are over a 10' date time

Would it be possible to always displays the 3 values?
Or by extrapolating the intermediate values (best) or by displaying 3 date times/values in the same tooltip.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not build-in, so you need to use tooltip formatter, find the closest point of current (by loops on each serie / each point, comparing x value) and then return values.